# pulp\pulp.py in solve, AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actual solve'

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda3

I am trying to create a python exe using pycharm with anaconda3.. my code runs and works fine in pycharm.. but when I run the exe file I get that error. My code performs linear programming using the Pulp library.

I tried specifying which solvers to use.. and many other things.

Comment: how did you make the exe file ?

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I used pyinstaller to make the exe file